# Why do I show up as a "New Contributor" even though I've posted several times?

Tags: support, new-users

On my [latest post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/249871/141465), I still have the "New Contributor" identifier under my user card, even though I have made 8 posts before this including questions.  Why is this?

Comment: It’s time based from your first post on that site; let me see if I can find the exact time.

Comment: You're still pretty new though

Comment: @Valorum True, but I thought "new contributor" meant that it's your first post.

Comment: @Anonymous - As far as I'm concerned, anyone who joined less than 2720 days ago is a new contributor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the original announcement of the "New Contributor" feature [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/278659)

> Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (**visible for a week following their first post**) letting them know that the person is new.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Beat me to it; took too long to find the relevant post. The indicator should still show for ~5 days for this user.

Comment: Also to clarify (and unless I’m mistaken) the indicator will disappear on all of the user’s posts, even those made in the first week, once that week has passed.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yep.